# How to handle authentication when user is login successfully first time using Laravel PWA?

Tags: laravel-5, progressive-web-apps

When user login from laravel PWA then no need to put user name password again up to user logout by himself (like android app user not logout upto which it will not ask for user name password) means remembering the user is already login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to first get user name and password then store this on local indexed db https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB and when next time user login then it will get auto login means fetch user name and password from local indexed db